# Reuse InputStream when BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options)

Tags: java, android, inputstream

```
InputStream stream = new URL(key).openStream();

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);

options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

/* i need reuse stream here, for decode stream again. */

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);

stream.close();

return bmp;
```

Comment: I'm using Android SDK :D :D :D :D

Comment: What do you want to do? At least write your purpose with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just reopen the stream from the URL

```
InputStream stream = new URL(key).openStream();
```

Or us a library like Guava (`ByteStreams`) to fully read the `InputStream` and assign the resulting bytes into a `ByteArrayInputStream`

```
InputStream stream = new URL(key).openStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteStreams.copy(stream, out);
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

// use it once
in.reset();
// use it again
```

Careful if your code calls `mark()` on the stream. If that happens, instead just create a new `ByteArrayInputStream` with the bytes from the `ByteArrayOutputStream` `out.toByteArray()`.