# Bitmap returns null pointer error Android

Tags: android

I am trying to pick image from gallery and setting it to the **imageview** in the **listview**, for that I working on a piece of code. **This code  throws NULL POINTER EXCEPTION**  , I am not able to solve the error. pls help me in this case

ContactInfoMoreOption.java

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {                
                View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);
                ImageView imgView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap bitmap=BirthdayCalculation.getThumbnailBitmap(is, 200);
                byte bitObj[]=BirthdayCalculation.convertImageToByte(bitmap);   
                ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                values.put(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO, bitObj);
                int count=getContentResolver().update(BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, BirthdayProvider.NUMBER+"='"+SearchListActivity.longClickValue+"'", null);
                if (count==1) {
                    finish();
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    Log.v("Photo Updated Successfully", "Photo Updated Successfully");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updation Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }              
              }
            }
        }
```

BirthdayCalculation.java

```
public static byte[] convertImageToByte(Bitmap bitmap){
      ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG,0,outputStream);
      return outputStream.toByteArray();
  }


public static Bitmap getThumbnailBitmap(InputStream is, final int thumbnailSize) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null, bounds);
        if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) {
            bitmap = null;
        }
        int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
                : bounds.outWidth;
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / thumbnailSize;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

### Error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
 ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
 dat=content://media/external/images/media/12532 }} to activity
 {com.android.project.birthdayreminder/com.android.project.birthdayreminder.ContactInfoMoreOption}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.project.birthdayreminder.BirthdayCalculation.convertImageToByte(BirthdayCalculation.java:565)
    at com.android.project.birthdayreminder.ContactInfoMoreOption.onActivityResult(ContactInfoMoreOption.java:720)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3145)
```

[Logcat Error Link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/12217649755/)!

Comment: Please post the full logcat.

Comment: on which line are you getting this error??

Comment: posted logcat code ,pls have a look

Comment: @vipul mittal --- Bitmap bitmap=BirthdayCalculation.getThumbnailBitmap(is, 200);
                byte bitObj[]=BirthdayCalculation.convertImageToByte(bitmap);

Comment: @karthik check my ans. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot read the same stream twice. Try following

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnailBitmap(InputStream is, final int thumbnailSize) {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null, bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) {
        bitmap = null;
    }
    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
            : bounds.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = originalSize / thumbnailSize;
    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, inSampleSize , inSampleSize , false);   
    return bitmap;
}
```

Once you read an `InputStream` it becomes empty that is why when you are trying to read it again to decode it returns null.

Comment: It throws Null pointer at Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, inSampleSize , inSampleSize , false);

Comment: your if condition if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) must be true

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting the inputstream, The Bitmap.decodeStream will return null if the inputstream is null.

See ->[`getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` throws FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549559/getcontentresolver-openinputstreamuri-throws-filenotfoundexception)

Comment: yes I am getting inputstream. When used Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options). It works ,but throws outofmemory error

Comment: As mentioned in below commnet http://stackoverflow.com/a/21451157/1825844, the same stream cannot be read twice.
You will have to make a copy or in your case, recreate the stream from the file.
Check ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768422/reuse-inputstream-when-bitmapfactory-decodestreamstream-null-options

Comment: Also consider using AsyncTask for bitmap processing. Bitmap processing is not supposed to be done on a UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In `getThumbnailBitmap()` you call `BitmapFactory#decodeStream()` twice with the same stream, as @vipulmittal pointed out. The stream doesn't get "empty" but as [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) explains:

> Decode an input stream into a bitmap. If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null. **The stream's position will be where ever it was after the encoded data was read.**

Which means that the steam will be at the end of the bitmap after one read, that's why the next read will fail and return `null`, so you'll end up passing `null` to `convertImageToByte()` which will fail with a `NullPointerException` when trying to execute `bitmap.compress(...)`.

You must `reset()` (if supported) or re-open the stream before calling `BitmapFactory#decodeStream()` a 2nd time. Since for `reset()` you'd need to buffer the whole bitmap, I would recommend you to simply close and re-open the stream:

```
public Bitmap getThumbnailBitmap(final Uri uri, final int thumbnailSize) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    final int originalSize;
    try {
        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        final BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bounds);
        originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight : bounds.outWidth;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    is = null;
    try {
        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        final BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / thumbnailSize;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```